# What is the release date of the WCF Data Services? (v3)

Tags: wcf-data-services

What is the release date of the WCF Data Services? (v3)

The Oct 2011 CTP is currently available at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/13/announcing-wcf-data-services-oct-2011-ctp-for-net-4-and-silverlight-4.aspx

According to a presentation given by Mike Flasko

http://video.ch9.ms/build/2011/slides/SAC-836T_Flasko.pptx

“WCF Data Services - **New release in Q1 2012**, covering most of next OData draft”

Is a more specific release date available?

As far as I understand, Microsofts fiscal year Q1 2012 ended on September 30, 2011.

Answer (score 0):

WCF Data Services 5.0 for OData v3 was released this week:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2012/04/09/new-wcf-data-services-release.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29306

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/04/09/wcf-data-services-5-0-rtm-release.aspx